# PrimeFaces 6.2 onCellEdit - getNewValue() nn esta recebendo o valor novo

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, datatable

Estou fazenho um projeto com PrimeFaces e em uma tela eu uso um DataTable com cellEdit e eu segui o exemplo do showcase certinho e tals porém o `getNewValue` e o `getOldValue` estão vindo nulos e isto esta quebrando a minha aplicação, a seguir o código:

Metodo onCellEdit:

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
    Object valorAntigo = event.getOldValue();
    Object valorNovo = event.getNewValue();

    if (valorNovo != null && !valorNovo.equals(valorAntigo)) { //ele nao esta entrando neste IF pq os valores estão nulos
        if (editEmItemSelecionado(Long.parseLong(event.getRowKey())) && !existeItemNaLista(Long.parseLong(event.getRowKey()))) {
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setIdItem(Long.parseLong(event.getRowKey()));
            item.setQuantidade((Short)valorNovo);
            quantidades.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Tela:

```
<p:dataTable id="lista" value="#{itemController.getDataModelCliente(p.idCategoria)}" var="i" selection="#{itemController.itensSelecionados}" editable="true" editMode="cell">
                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" update="lista" process="@this" partialSubmit="true" listener="#{itemController.onCellEdit}"/>

                <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="text-align: center">
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Item">
                    <h:outputText value="#{i.nomeItem}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{i.descricao}" rendered="#{i.descricao != null}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="N/A" rendered="#{i.descricao.equalsIgnoreCase(null)}"/>
                    <br/>
                    <h:outputText value="N/A" rendered="#{i.tempoPreparo == 0}"/>
                    <h:outputText value="#{i.tempoPreparo} Minutos" rendered="#{i.tempoPreparo != 0}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Preço">
                    <h:outputText value="R$ #{i.preco}" rendered="#{i.categoria.idCategoria.equals(p.idCategoria)}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Quantidade">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"> <h:outputText value="#{i.quantidade}"/> </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"> <p:spinner value="#{i.quantidade}" min="1"/> </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Procurando na internet eu percebi que tem mais gente com este mesmo problema que eu ou parecido porém nn achei uma resposta ainda, pelo menos não achei uma que funcionasse para mim, alguem pode me ajudar?

Edit 1:

Perrcebi que o que ta acontecendo é que ele nn ta mandando o valor novo e por isso ele tava vindo nulo pq o valor antigo tava nulo, mas ainda nn resolvi o problema, eu nn consigo receber o valor novo, alguem sabe o porque?

Answer (score 0):

Achei meu erro, o erro esta na linha `<p:dataTable id="lista" value="#{itemController.getDataModelCliente(p.idCategoria)}"...` eu estou usando apenas o meto `get` do meu objeto DataModel. A parte boa é que eu achei o erro, a parte ruim é que minha lógica foi pro saco pq eu estava fazendo (sei que o DataTable ja é dinamico) um DataTable "mais dinamico", é meio dificil de explicar mas só de vc ler o código talvez vc vai entender o que eu to querendo dizer, vou ter que pensar em outra lógica aqui, flw!